# Регулярные выражения Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь разбить выражение на массив при помощи pattern.split
по одному из этих символов (+,-,(,),*,/,). Проблема в том, что выражение разбивается, но присутствуют пустые строки.
Как мне от них избавиться?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] Array;
    String input = "(2.0+34)*56";   
    Array = chisla(input);
    for(String w: Array) {
        System.out.println(w);
    }   
}
public static String[] chisla(String str1){    
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\+|\\*|/|-|\\(|\\)");     
    String[] arr = pattern.split(str1);
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обнаружил много советов поставить лимит в методе split, но это сработало не так как ожидалось, потому привожу код как можно просто вырезать пустые строки из массива. Непосредственное удаление строк происходит в методе **removeEmptyStrings**

```
//Основной метод приложения
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] Array;
    String input = "(2.0+34)*56";
    Array = chisla(input);
    for(String w: Array) {
        System.out.println(w);
    }
}

//Метод получения чисел
public static String[] chisla(String str1){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\+|\\*|/|-|\\(|\\)");
    String[] arrayWithEmpty = pattern.split(str1);
    return removeEmptyStrings(arrayWithEmpty);
}

//Удаление пустых строк из массива
private static String[] removeEmptyStrings(String[] arrayWithEmpty) {
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i < arrayWithEmpty.length ; i++) {
        if (!arrayWithEmpty[i].isEmpty()){
            strings.add(arrayWithEmpty[i]);
        }
    }
    return strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
}
```